# jQuery Menu Help

Tags: jquery, menu, fadeout, slide

I am trying to create a jQuery nav menu where it slides down to show child UL when hover and fadeout when mouse is moved off and I have the following code which acts very different in different browsers.

Hoping you guys can spot the problem.

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){ 
 // menu effects
 this.navLi = jQuery('nav ul li').children('ul').hide().end();
  this.navLi.hover(function() {
   // mouseover
  jQuery(this).find('> ul').stop(true, true).slideDown(300);
  }, function() {
   // mouseout
   jQuery(this).find('> ul').stop(true, true).fadeOut(300);   
 });
});
```

IE7 and 8 slide and fadeout works
FF slide works fadeout does not work
Chrome slide works only first time and second time it doesn't work and fadeout does not work at all

Safari same as Chrome as they are both webkit...

Let me know if you guys know why..most appreciated.

Comment: Ok I solved it...it was because prior to adding jQuery effect, there is a declared "display:none" on the children UL so now with jQuery I need to first set the display:block to the child UL and then call the hide() function...that fixed it...

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the problem is your initial selector. It should be `jQuery('#nav ul li')` if `nav` is an element id or `jQuery('.nav ul li')` if it's a class. See a stripped down example based on your code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ZFHrd/).

Comment: thanks for the reply but no, it is not the selector...Recall that it works in all browsers but just some it doesn't work on second hover and some the fadeout doesn't work. thanks for trying though..